# ¿Como funciona la precedencia del operador modulo (combinado con otros operadores) en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operador, sintaxis, modulos

En algunos libros académicos encontré que python, para sus operadores aritméticos tiene prioridades y asociatividades específicas que guían el orden de la ejecución de las operaciones.

Aquí están los valores relacionados para los operadores aritméticos básicos (tabla encontrada en un libro de python y coherente con otros sitios web, tales como https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/precedence-associativity):

[image: Características de los operadores en python]

No obstante cuando realizo algunas expresiones en python obtengo un resultado que no es coherente con esa jerarquía y asociatividad de operaciones:

Doy ejemplos:

```
>>>-13//-2
6
```

Lo cual es coherente (primero se realiza el cambio de signo de ambos términos (-13) y (-2) y luego la división entera.

```
>>>1-13//-2
8
```

Que es también es coherente. Siguiendo el raciocinio dado en la tabla, primero se cambiaría el signo del 2 → (-2), en seguida, se realiza la división entera que da -7 al ser -7 el valor menor a -6.5 que daría el resultado de la división normal; por último se debería realizar la resta 1-(-7) = 8  y de ahí el resultado.

No obstante, al realizar:

```
>>>13//-2%2
1
```

Este resultado no parece obedecer la asociatividad por la izquierda de los operadores de división entera y módulo que pertenecen a la misma precedencia (hierarchy). Tampoco puedo llegar al mismo resultado siguiendo la precedencia y asociatividad. Dado que primero se debería hacer el cambio de signo 2→(-2), luego se debe asociar por la izquierda la división entera dando (-7) y por último se debe hacer la operación del módulo cuyo resultado debería ser -1.

¿Hay alguna cosa que no esté teniendo encuenta?
¿Es incorrecta mi forma de usar los valores de precedencia y asociatividad?
O se debe a alguna consideración sobre python que ignoro.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tu comprensión de la precedencia y asociatividad es correcta. Lo que no estás teniendo en cuenta es que el resultado del módulo es positivo:

```
>>> (-7)%2
1
```

Esto se debe a que (por convención) en Python el resultado de la operación módulo tiene siempre el mismo signo que el divisor (2 en este caso). Este convenio es diferente al que usa el C por ejemplo, en el que se conserva el signo del numerador.

### ¿Por qué?

La lógica detrás de esta decisión es que suele ser más útil hacerlo así en la práctica. Por ejemplo, considera usar módulo 7 para calcular el día de la semana. Si el año comenzó en lunes y estamos a 27 de enero ¿qué día de la semana es?

Respuesta:

```
>>> 27 % 7
6
```

Es decir, sería domingo. Y ¿qué día de la semana es 28 días antes?

```
>>> (27-28) % 7
6
```

Es decir, era también domingo. En un lenguaje como C el resultado habría sido -1, que no es válido como día de la semana (y habría que corregir sumándole 7).

Observa que en módulo 7, el -1 equivale al 6 (o el 6 equivale a -1, como prefieras).

En el caso particular en que divides entre 2 la cosa es más confusa, ya que el -1 equivale al 1. No se trata simplemente de cambiar de signo al resultado si es negativo, sino de sumarle el divisor. Sólo que en este caso particular -1 da como resultado 1, de ahí probablemente tu confusión.

Answer (score 5):

Para complementar la respuesta de abulafia, te recomiendo siempre consultar la [documentacion oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations). Alli leemos

> The modulo operator always yields a result with the same sign as its
> second operand (or zero); the absolute value of the result is strictly
> smaller than the absolute value of the second operand.

Que medio traducido es

> El operador modulo siempre devuelve un resultado con el mismo signo
> que el segundo operador (o cero); el valor absoluto del resultado es
> estrictamente mas pequeño que el valor absoluto del segundo operador.

Y para responder una de tus preguntas, la forma en la que entiendes la precedencia de los operadores en Python [es correcta](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). (No voy a poner la tabla completa de la documentacion oficial porque es muy larga)

P.D. En mi opinion, Python es uno de los proyectos mejor documentados.